# how to set key of the object from the function parameters in javascript es6

Tags: javascript

I have to generate an array of object. I'm trying to implement the following but not getting as I desired.

```
const paramsArray = []

const insertFun(key, value) {
   paramsArray.push({ Key: value });
// desired paramsArray [{'area[]': 'laurinburg drive' }]
// but producing [{key:'laurinburg drive'}]
}

insertFun('area[]', 'laurinburg drive')
```

Please explain how to get the desired one.

Comment: Read about **Computed property names** `->` `{ [key]: value }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

```js
const paramsArray = [];
function insertFun(key, value) {
  paramsArray.push({
    [key]: value
  });
}

insertFun('area[]', 'laurinburg drive');

console.log(paramsArray);
```